# UIView loaded from nib and removing it from superview causing UIButton to revert to nib text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am loading a xib:

```
EventFormView *formView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EventFormView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
formView.delegate = self;

[formView loadEvent:event];
```

I have a button in the nib:

[image]

in the `awakeFromNib:` method, I change the button's text:

```
self.button.titleLabel.text = @"Done";
```

When I add `formView` to `self.view`, it displays the "Done" text.

Pressing the button will remove it from `self.view`:

```
-(void)removeForm {
    DLog(@"fired");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

This works but the button reverts back to the original text of "Test" while it fades out. (I have a header UIView that also reverts back to the nib's background color instead of the color I assign in the `awakeFromNib`).

This if the first time I've really worked with nib's, so not sure if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use "[self.button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal]" instead?

Comment: With UIButton you need to use the setTitle:forState: method, because UIKit may change the label on you depending on the state of the button.  Cheers!

Comment: Can you make an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UIButton you need to use the setTitle:forState: method, because UIKit may change the label on you depending on the state of the button.  Try:

```
[self.button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```